Add User Assigned Managed Identity in a Function App Template Conditionally
Is there a way to update the below template to include IDENTITY_RESOURCE_ID1 conditionally if addIdentity1 parameter is set to true?
{
    "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
    "name": "[parameters('name')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
    "kind": "functionapp",
    "location": "[parameters('location')]",
    "identity": {
        "type": "SystemAssigned,UserAssigned",
        "userAssignedIdentities": {
            "IDENTITY_RESOURCE_ID1": {},
            "IDENTITY_RESOURCE_ID2": {}
        }
    },
    "tags": null,
    // ...
}


Hope you have explored usage of conditions in template.. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-tutorial-use-conditions

You can use the union function.
Here is a bicep sample (main.bicep):
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param name string
param addIdentity1 bool

resource webApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2018-11-01' = {
  name: name
  location: location
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned, UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: union(
      {
        'IDENTITY_RESOURCE_ID2': {}
      },
      addIdentity1
        ? {
            'IDENTITY_RESOURCE_ID1': {}
          }
        : {}
    )
  }
}

Running the Az Cli command az bicep build --file .\main.bicep, will give you this ARM template:
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
  "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
  "name": "[parameters('name')]",
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "identity": {
    "type": "SystemAssigned, UserAssigned",
    "userAssignedIdentities": "[union(createObject('IDENTITY_RESOURCE_ID2', createObject()), if(parameters('addIdentity1'), createObject('IDENTITY_RESOURCE_ID1', createObject()), createObject()))]"
  }
}

